# Samba server - CIFS mount issues

Tags: samba

Background:

I have a samba cifs server. It is not joined to a domain, but has a keytab for an MIT kerberosV realm.

Kerberized mounts (e.g. `mount -t cifs //cifs.example.com/groups /mnt/cifs -o sec=krb5i`) work from Linux clients. 
Kerberized mounts from AD joined windows machines (joined to a domain configured with a trust to the Kerberos Realm). Password based mounts don't work for Linux clients (not a big deal).

Password based mounts for non AD joined Windows clients *kind of* work. Using explorer to go to `\\cifs.example.com\groups` will not work, and no password prompt will appear. However, if `\\cifs.example.com\groups` is mounted as a letter drive, the dialog will not complete, but the drive mapping will be established and work, and the dialog box can be canceled at this point while retaining the mount.

**Question:**

1. How can a make the UNC path prompt for a password on non AD joined Windows machines?

Configs:

hostname: cifs.example.com
realm: EXAMPLE.COM
distro: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
samba version: samba-3.6.9-167.el6_5.x86_64

*smb.conf*

```
syslog only = yes
syslog = 3

server string = %h server (Samba, CentOS)
workgroup = EXAMPLE.COM
security = ads
realm = EXAMPLE.COM
create krb5 conf = no
kerberos method = secrets and keytab
server signing = auto
smb encrypt = auto
smb ports = 445
use sendfile = yes

map to guest = Bad User
guest account = nobody

wins support = no
dns proxy = no

load printers = no
printing = bsd
printcap name = /dev/null
disable spoolss = yes

hide files = /Desktop.ini/$RECYCLE.BIN/Thumbs.db/~$.*/

[home]
path = /export/home/
writeable = yes
guest ok = no
browseable = no
create mask = 0600
directory mask = 0700

[groups]
path = /export/groups
writeable = yes
guest ok = no
browseable = yes
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0770
```

*

*klist -k*

```
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   8 host/cifs.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   8 host/cifs.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   8 host/cifs.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   8 host/cifs.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   8 cifs/cifs.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   8 cifs/cifs.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   8 cifs/cifs.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   8 cifs/cifs.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

*getsebool -a | grep -e cifs -e samba*

```
allow_ftpd_use_cifs --> off
cobbler_use_cifs --> off
git_cgi_use_cifs --> off
git_system_use_cifs --> off
httpd_use_cifs --> off
qemu_use_cifs --> on
rsync_use_cifs --> off
samba_create_home_dirs --> off
samba_domain_controller --> off
samba_enable_home_dirs --> off
samba_export_all_ro --> off
samba_export_all_rw --> off
samba_portmapper --> off
samba_run_unconfined --> off
samba_share_fusefs --> off
samba_share_nfs --> off
sanlock_use_samba --> off
tftp_use_cifs --> off
use_samba_home_dirs --> off
virt_use_samba --> off
```

*/etc/pam.d/samba*

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required pam_nologin.so
auth       include  password-auth
account    include  password-auth
session    include  password-auth
password   include  password-auth
```

*/etc/pam.d/password-auth*

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to change `max protocol` from the default `NT1` to max protocol = [`SMB2`](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_3.6_Features_added/changed#SMB2_support).